# We needed to find an example where $\sum x_{n}$ and $\sum y_{n}$ do not converge absolutely, but $\sum x_{n}y_{n}$ does.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**1. Question**

We needed to find an example where $\sum x_{n}$ and $\sum y_{n}$ do not converge absolutely, but $\sum x_{n}y_{n}$ does.

**Answer:**

I thought that is $\sum x_{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{n=\infty}\frac{1}{n^{3}}$ and $\sum y_{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{n=\infty}n$, then it works right? Since $x_{n}y_{n} = \frac{1}{n^{2}}$, and this converges by the p-series test, but individually $x_{n}$ does not converge.

**2. Question**

Find an example where $\sum x_{n}, \sum y_{n}, \sum x_{n}y_{n}$are absolutely convergent, are not just finite sums, and
($\sum x_{n}$) ($\sum y_{n} )$ $\ne$ ($\sum x_{n}y_{n}$).

**Answer:**

For this I used the following resource:

https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/absoluteconvergence.aspx

And my examples are $\sum x_{n} = \sum\frac{1}{n^{2}} , \sum y_{n} = \sum \frac{sin(n)}{n^{3}}, \sum x_{n}y_{n} = \sum \frac{sin(n)}{n^5}$.

But what is a finite sum? Does my example satisfy all properties ( $\sum x_{n}, \sum y_{n}, \sum x_{n}y_{n}$are absolutely convergent, are not just finite sums, and ($\sum x_{n}$)($\sum y_{n}) $ $\ne$ ($\sum x_{n}y_{n}$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example for the first question doesn’t work, because $\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac1{n^3}$ does converge absolutely. Try letting $x_n=y_n=\frac1n$ instead. Or let $x_n=y_n=\frac{(-1)^n}n$, in which case $\sum_{n\ge 0}x_n$ and $\sum_{n\ge 0}y_n$ converge, but not abolutely.

A finite sum is a series with only finitely many non-zero terms. Examples for the second question are trivial if we allow finite series; for instance, $$(1+1+0+0+0+\ldots)^2\ne 1\cdot1+1\cdot1+0\cdot0+0\cdot0+\ldots\,.$$ By the way, you’ve a misplaced parenthesis in the question: it should be

$$\left(\sum_nx_n\right)\left(\sum_ny_n\right)\ne\sum_nx_ny_n\,.$$

For a straightforward example let $x_n=y_n=\frac1{2^n}$. Then

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}x_n=\sum_{n\ge 0}y_n=\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac12\right)^n=2\,,$$

but

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}x_ny_n=\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac12\cdot\frac12\right)^n=\sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\frac14\right)^n=\frac43\ne 2^2\,.$$